# KOMA-Script: How to colour just the section numbers

Tags: sectioning, color, koma-script

I have added a splash of colour to my thesis and found it looked quite nice. The theme is: Chapter and Section headings are a dark blue, and the numbering is a brighter blue.

I managed to do this for the `\part` and `\chapter` sections in this `scrreprt` class, however I cannot seem to find a way to use the only apparently available control for other sections being the following: `\othersectionlevelsformat{sectioning name}{}{counter output}`.

How do I change just the colour of the numbering for `\section` `\subsection`, `\subsubsection` and `\paragraph`? Would I have to start using the `titlesec` package?

Please find below my MWE. Thank you

```
\documentclass[
DIV=11,
%fontsize=12,
twoside,
headinclude=false,
titlepage=firstiscover,
abstract=true,
headsepline=true,
footsepline=true,
chapterprefix=true, %this allows for editing of the chapter titles
headings=big,
bibliography=totoc,%adds unnumbered Bibliography chapter to toc
captions=tableheading
]{scrreprt}

%%% Packages
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{minitoc} 
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
%\usepackage{mathchars}
%\usepackage{acro}
%\usepackage[hidelinks
%,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=4 %This is for the appendix command formulated
%]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\linespread{1.5} %imperial uses 1.5 
\flushbottom

%%%%%%%%%%% ToC DEPTH LEVEL
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % number subsubsection
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} % list subsubsection
\setcounter{minitocdepth}{4}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Entry of TOC LOF LOT
\def\body{
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \cleardoublepage
\linespread{1.25}
    %%% MINITOC
    \dominitoc
    % MINITOC styling
    \renewcommand{\mtcfont}{\normalsize\fontfamily{jkpss}\selectfont}
    \renewcommand{\mtcSfont}{\normalsize\bf\fontfamily{jkpss}\selectfont}

    \mtcsettitlefont{minitoc}{\bf\fontfamily{jkpss}\selectfont}
    \mtcsettitle{minitoc}{Contents \textcolor{white}{mmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmn} Page}

    %%% TOC
    \tableofcontents
    \addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par} %Adds the word Page
    \cleardoublepage

    %%% LOF
    \listoffigures \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
    \addtocontents{lof}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par} %Adds the word Page
    \cleardoublepage

    %%% LOT
    \listoftables \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables} 
    \addtocontents{lot}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par} %Adds the word Page
    \cleardoublepage


    \pagestyle{headings}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}


    %%% CHAPTER STYLING
    \addtokomafont{chapterprefix}{\raggedleft \linespread{1}}
    \setkomafont{chapter}{\color{DodgerBlue4}\fontsize{40}{30}\selectfont}

    \addtokomafont{section}{\color{DodgerBlue4}\fontsize{20}{24}\selectfont}
    \addtokomafont{subsection}{\color{DodgerBlue4}\fontsize{18}{22}\selectfont}
    \addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\color{DodgerBlue4}\fontsize{16}{19}\selectfont}
    \addtokomafont{paragraph}{\color{DodgerBlue4}\fontsize{15}{19}\selectfont}

    \renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \mbox{\scalebox{0.80}{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}}%
    \scalebox{3.5}{\color{DeepSkyBlue2}\thechapter}\enskip}}

}

\begin{document}

\body

\chapter{First Chapter}
\linespread{1}
\dictum[Neil deGrasse Tyson]{The good thing about science is that it's true whether or not you believe in it.}


\minitoc

Here is some introduction

\section{Here is a section for the minitoc}
Bla bla.

\subsection{And why not a subsection too}
Just to spice things up a bit.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\renewcommand*{\othersectionlevelsformat}[3]{\textcolor{DeepSkyBlue2}{#3}\autodot\enskip}
```

A little explanation:

As you said in your question, `\othersectionlevelsformat` is given 3 arguments, so, when you (re)define it, it needs to have 3 arguments, hence the `[3]`. And the definition only uses the third argument (where the counter is given) so you only need to use `#3`.

By the way, the examples in pages 97 an 98 of scrguien.pdf are self explaining.

Comment: Thank you, if it's not too much trouble could you explain a little bit how the command works please? I don't intuitively understand the `[3]` and `{#3}` parts.

Comment: Done, but I really just looked into the documentation.

Comment: Ah ok that makes more sense now, well I had read them but I am still rather new to LaTeX and command jargon I didn't realise that that was what inserting those parts meant, I read them but I didn't know how to use them I was writing `\othersectionlevelsformat}{section} etc...` as it said that `\othersectionlevelsformat{sectioning name}` in the manual.

Comment: Aha :) The thing is that KOMA-Script *uses* that command inside of the sectioning commands, and *it uses* it in that way: `\othersectionlevelsformat{…}{…}{…}`. So you needed to redefine it (with three arguments), and make use of them as you wish; in this case only the third one was relevant since it's the one where the counter is given.