# Section numbers colored

Tags: sectioning, color, koma-script

I want to color the section and subsection numbers in my document.

I tried the solution here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193186/80972 but it doesn't work for me.

Here's an example using that solution

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\renewcommand*{\othersectionlevelsformat}[3]{\textcolor{LightSteelBlue}{#3}\autodot\enskip}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

Bla bla.

\subsection{A subsection}

Bla.

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see the numbers are still black.

Any help is appreciated. Best regards.

Comment: I get colored numbers. How do you compile the document (pdflatex, dvips, ...?) Which color driver (see the `.log` file for `<driver>.def`, e.g. `pdftex.def`) is used? Try `\textcolor{red}{foo}` in the text to check, if colors are working at all. Which version of KOMA-Script (class `scrartcl`, see `.log` file) are you using? Maybe it's too old.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek KOMA-script went into some crazy changes within the last few months. Just checked, no coloured section numbers. So, apparently no backwards compatibility :-(

Comment: To get into compatibility mode, use `\documentclass[version=3.15]{scrartcl}`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Maybe is it too new? `Document Class: scrartcl 2015/05/06 v3.17a KOMA-Script document class (article)`

Comment: BTW: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command `\othersectionlevelsformat`, in latest versions of KOMA-Script, doesn't work as before any more (to say the truth I think it's there for backwards compatibility only).

Now every sectioning command has its own formatting command. Here's a list:

```
\partformat
\chapterformat
\sectionformat
\subsectionformat
\subsubsectionformat
\paragraphformat
\subparagraphformat
```

So, instead of using `\othersectionlevelsformat` you will have to use `\sectionformat` and `\subsectionformat` in this way:

```
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \textcolor{LightSteelBlue}{\thesection}\autodot\enskip%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \textcolor{LightSteelBlue}{\thesubsection}\autodot\enskip%
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \textcolor{LightSteelBlue}{\thesection}\autodot\enskip%
}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \textcolor{LightSteelBlue}{\thesubsection}\autodot\enskip%
}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

Bla bla.

\subsection{A subsection}

Bla.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Handy, I'd say. `;-)` I think the new method is good, because it separates what should be kept separated. What's missing in the new release is a hook executed for *all* section levels. One could use it or not; but this would avoid code duplication like in this case.

Comment: @egreg There is one for all, font element `disposition`, but it adds a font def for the whole section. Maybe a feature request is in order.

Comment: @egreg It's handy to have separate commands for different sectioning commands, as it was handy to have `\othersectionlevelsformat` for all of them. Waiting for a feature request by Johannes_B, if you want to use `\othersectionlevelsformat` you have to `\relax` all others commands (e.g. `\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\relax}`) or use KOMA classes in compatibility mode...

Comment: Read the link and learned how to accept and vote up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

You can use `\newkomafont` to set a default font style for the numbers for all section levels and for the single section levels. Later these defaults can be changed using `\setkomafont` and `\addtokomafont`. Of course the `\...format` commands must be redefined in a way that they use the related `\usekomafont{...}` commands. Then it is easy to change the color of the numbers for all levels or to change the font size etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}[2015/02/07]
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\newkomafont{secnum}{\color{LightSteelBlue}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand*\do[1]{%
  \newkomafont{#1number}{}%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname#1format\endcsname{%
    {\usekomafont{secnum}\usekomafont{#1number}\csname the#1\endcsname\autodot}\enskip%
  }%
}
\docsvlist{section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
Bla bla.
\subsection{A subsection}
Bla.
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\KOMAScriptVersion

\setkomafont{secnum}{\color{Chartreuse}}
\addtokomafont{sectionnumber}{\Huge}
\section{A section}
Bla bla.
\subsection{A subsection}
Bla.
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\KOMAScriptVersion

\addtokomafont{sectionnumber}{\color{Maroon}}
\setkomafont{subsectionnumber}{\color{BlueViolet}\Large}
\setkomafont{subsubsectionnumber}{\color{Fuchsia}}
\section{A section}
Bla bla.
\subsection{A subsection}
Bla.
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\KOMAScriptVersion
\end{document}
```

---

**Former answer**

Here is another suggestion defining a command to color the different section levels

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}[2015/02/07]
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{SecnumColor}{LightSteelBlue}

\newcommand*\colorsecnum[2][SecnumColor]{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname#2format\endcsname{%
  \textcolor{#1}{\csname the#2\endcsname}\autodot\enskip
}}

\colorsecnum{section}
\colorsecnum{subsection}
\colorsecnum[orange]{subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
Bla bla.
\subsection{A subsection}
Bla.
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\KOMAScriptVersion
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This also works, but it seems only a workaround.

Comment: At least my first suggestion is no workaround because it also uses the new commands `\sectionformat` etc.

Comment: Can you add the `version=<number>` thing, instead of `\relax`ing the commands? What do you think, feature request for `\newkomafont{secnumfont}{}`?`

Comment: @Johannes_B I think there is no way to restrict `version=3.15` to this feature. But I have added an example using `\newkomafont` etc.

Comment: You are right. Would you think that would be worth implementing in the classes/`scrkernel-sections.dtx`?

Comment: @Johannes_B I agree to Markus: Man muss nicht alles machen, was möglich ist. (One does not have to do everything that is possible .)

Comment: ok, changing it is still easy, if you know how to do it or find your answer.