# Colored Section Numbers

Tags: sectioning, color, titlesec

I would like to colour the section, subsection, and subsubsection **numbers** in my thesis document. I tried before the solution at the end of this thread:[Section numbers colored](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252627/section-numbers-colored)
but I get the error that there is a clash with the colour package.

I am using an overleaf template by Andre Miéde: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/classic-thesis-style-v4-dot-2-by-andre-miede/dwgtvykzvdtk

Please excuse my naivety, I've only started learning LaTeX recently

Here's an example of my code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\input{classicthesis-config}

\usepackage{classicthesis} 

   \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{SecnumColor}{teal}

\newcommand*\colorsecnum[2][SecnumColor]{%
  \expandafter\renewcommand\csname#2format\endcsname{%
  \textcolor{#1}{\csname the#2\endcsname}\autodot\enskip
}}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \section{A section}
    
    Bla
    
    \subsection{A subsection}
    
    Bla.
    
    \end{document}
```

and what the classicthesis-config includes regarding sectioning:

```
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
  
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{@parts}}{
    \newcommand{\ct@parttext}{\relax} 
    \newcommand{\ctparttext}[1]{\renewcommand{\ct@parttext}{#1 \relax}} 
\titleformat{\part}[display]
    {\normalfont\centering\large}
 {\thispagestyle{empty}\partname~\MakeTextUppercase{\thepart}}{1em}
    {\color{Violet}\spacedallcaps}[\bigskip\normalfont\normalsize\color{Violet}\begin{quote}\ct@parttext\end{quote}]
}{\relax}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@linedheaders}}
{\titleformat{\chapter}[display]            
    {\relax}{\raggedleft{\color{myheadingscolour}\chapterNumber\thechapter} \\ }{0pt}
  
    {\vspace*{.9\baselineskip}\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule]
}{ 
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\relax}{\mbox{}\oldmarginpar{\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}\color{myheadingscolour}\chapterNumber\thechapter}}{0pt}
    {\raggedright\spacedallcaps}[\normalsize\vspace*{.8\baselineskip}\titlerule] 
}

\titleformat{\section}
    {\relax}{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}}{1em}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}

\titleformat{\subsection}
    {\relax}{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesubsection}}}{1em}{\normalsize\itshape}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
    {\relax}{\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesubsubsection}}}{1em}{\normalsize\itshape}        

\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
    {\normalfont\normalsize}{\theparagraph}{0pt}{\spacedlowsmallcaps}
    \renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace*{\labelsep}\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}   
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@nochapters}}
    {\relax}
    {\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{1.2\baselineskip}}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1.25\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip} 
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1.25\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{1\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `classicthesis` already loads `xcolor` with `dvipsnames` as an option, hence the option clash when you try to load `xcolor` again with `svgnames`. Now, a question to you is:

> Do you really need the `svgnames` option?

Your MWE uses the color `teal` which is part of the base set in `xcolor`, which means that it should build fine if you just remove the line

```
 \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
```

from your code. If you are happy with only using colors from the base set (19) and from the `dvips` named set (68), then you can be fine doing just this.

If you **must** use the named colors from the `svg` set (151), then one option is to issue

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
```

*before* you `\usepackage{classicthesis}`, so that `xcolor` will be loaded with both `dvipsnames` and `svgnames` as options. This, however, comes with a huge caveat, in that the `svg` and `dvips` sets have significant overlap in names, for example, both define "Cyan" and "Fuschia" and "ForestGreen" and "LimeGreen" but assign different colors to them. The way the package is constructed the `svg` version will be used when there is a clash. The `xcolor` manual has a discussion of what to do in this case if you want to use the `dvips` versions instead; it requires more work in your context as you are not loading `xcolor` directly but relying on `classicthesis`.

Comment: thank you for answering, that was quite illuminating. I only need the teal colour from the dips named set. I've removed the line from the code but it did nothing to the colour of the numbers (they stayed black). Something else in the classic thesis template might be blocking it but I have not figured it out, yet.